# Azure Default Logs

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and I deployed a flask application to Azure. Just curious where Azure save the logs if I print (console log) something in the application. Just curious if there is any log folder by default or do I have to setup one of my own? If so, how can I create one?

Its creating the log file but it is not writing anything to it,

```
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

sys.stdout = open('D:/home/LogFiles/app.log', 'w')

print("I am here")

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find application logs on `Kudu` with 2 ways:

1.On the portal:

[image]

2.Just access URL directly in the browser:

```
https://<Your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

Then please check log files in the path :`D:\home\LogFiles>`

[image]

In addition , you could turn on the button to collect logs or store logs in blob container on the portal.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer :***

After some testing, I found that Flask Azure app only records the `fastcgi` level logs on `KUDU`, although I've turned on the diagnostics log switch which I metioned above. I found C# azure app can record the console log after the diagnostics log configuration, but the azure Python app does not.

As I know , everything you output using `print` goes to the standard output(by default).

So , I recommand a workaround to deal with this is to redirect the standard output of your scripts to some files on KUDU:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = open('<Absolute path on Kudu(such as D:\home\LogFiles\app.log)>', 'w')
>>> print('Hello World!')
```

You can configure the above code as a global variable.

Comment: That's the first place I checked. It contains deployment logs, but not the application logs, unfortunately. I am trying to log simple `print` statements to debug the application.

Comment: @HafizTemuri Thanks for your waiting, please see my update answer.

Comment: please replace the \  with  `/` in the path, cuz that works for me.