# Deploying NextJS 14 web app with SSR and app router using Azure Devops

Tags: next.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, server-side-rendering

We built a Nextjs 14 with an App Router and SSR website because of certain regularities and data protection. Our entire codebase, CI/CD pipeline, and hosting service need to sit on Azure DevOps. However, after following so many tutorials and getting success in build and deployment to Azure Web App service, the website just won't run.

I have tried the pm2 startup command but just won't be able to find the next module even though I've already copied the next file to node_modules.

- Have tried nextjs standalone build and the "node server.js" start-up command but have issues with getting static files.

If anyone has encountered this specific use case, please reach out and help. Appreciate it!

Comment: Since the deployment is successful but website won't run, to narrow down the issue, please confirm: 1. If you build and deploy locally, will the website work fine? 2. If it works locally, please download the build result(artifact) from build pipeline, deploy based on the artifact content from local machine, will the website work fine? In addition, it's recommended to add some screenshots or error details in the statement for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating one **`NextJs app`** with **`SSR`** and routing and tried the deployment via **`Azure DevOps pipline`** and it loaded successfully, Refer below:-

My **[Github Repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/nextssr)**.

I tried deploying via normal **`Azure DevOps pipeline`** but
the app failed to load.

In order to deploy your **NextJJs app successfully via Azure DevOps pipeline, Refer my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474119/next-js-with-custom-express-node-js-deployment-on-azure/76523140#).** Where I have built the App and used **`next start`** command as a startup script.

Alternatively, When I tried deployment via **VS Code** the **app worked successfully**, Refer below:-

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]