# Azure Web App & Typescript : "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: typescript, azure

I deploy a NodeJS server written in Typescript to Azure Web App through VS19, the project works internally but returns permission issue when published to Azure.

The base template used for this project is "Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application" available in VS19.

As I understand it, Azure uses IIS to host Typescript applications in the form of Azure Web App therefore it needs a web.config file which has been provided below as well.

I simply adapted the "app.js" to "index.js" which is the name of my app main source file.

Currently when accessing to the Kudu web app shell, i can see that the output of the Typescript compilation is in :

```
|-wwwroot
|---dist
|-----src
|--------index.js
|--------index.js.map
|--------environments
|--------middlewares
...
```

Where in reality index.js and index.js.map should normally be at the same lvl as src.

Regardless I've modified the configuration of the Azure Web App to redirect it's root virtual path to : site\wwwroot\dist\src.

[image: new_virtual_path]

Without this change, the application would return : **"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."**

Instead, now it can at least try to access it but i get denied with a permission issue in the form of : **"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."**

Should i change the web.config ? I have very few documentation / information as to how to to do this and if it's really the right direction.

The folder structure looks like the following :

[image: folder_structure]

**tsconfig.json** :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json** (excluding all the dependencies) :

```
{
  "name": "projet",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "test-watch": "jest --verbose --watchAll",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src -e js,ts,json --exec \"ts-node src/index.ts\"",
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    ...
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
        <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
                </rule>     
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Enter SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT for the setting key.

Enter true for the setting value. I got the same error but resolved by using this setting.

Answer (score 0):

- I created Node.js Express app in my Local by using required commands in terminal. it runs successfully in my Local.
- I have deployment issue in Visualstudio2019, Visual studio2022. So, I tried in Visual studio code.
- I created Web application in azure.

[image]

- I have successfully deployed Express app into web app in azure. to check given below.
  [image]

While I was running the web app, I also got the same error. check the below attached image.

[image]

- Below is my file structure path.

[image]

- After I added new application settings to my web app it is running successfully.
- `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` this is mentioned as `True`.

**Check below:**
[image]

Comment: I have this setting in my deployment too, but i get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" instead.

Comment: For more details refer this [SO_LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168500/node-js-on-azure-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)  and  [Refer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11848).